# Is there a web version of a chess clock for mobile phones without (distracting) advertisements?

Tags: chess-clocks, websites

I am looking for a very simple Chess Clock (simple design - see picture) to use from the phone browser WITHOUT having to download an app. I already know apps who have this I am looking for a **web version**! 
This is an example for a good *app*:

[image: This is a very good example of an app]

[image: Chess Clock app design]

And [here](https://www.online-stopwatch.com/full-screen-chess-clock/) is an example of a bad web version with bad design and too many distractions, looks especially bad on mobile:

[image: mobile version of bad web version example]

Answer (score 5):

**Best Solution:**

- [chessclock.org](https://chessclock.org/) - add the website to the home screen on your phone and tilt the phone to the side

Added in the comments: [chessclock.iphonemarks.com](http://chessclock.iphonemarks.com/)

---

*Original suggestions:*

- [skakur.dk](http://www.skakur.dk/)
- [ksloan.net/chessclock](https://ksloan.net/chessclock/)

Comment: The last one is very close to what I'm looking for, but all three of them are lacking the mobile aspect I specifically mentioned in the question. I have you a like and I really appreciate your answer, but could you please add to your answer that it is lacking this aspect?

Comment: @ChagaiFriedlander Would http://chessclock.iphonemarks.com/ suit your requirements?

Comment: That is for mobile, yes thanks! chessclock.org with the layout of chessclock.iphonemarks.com would be amazing! I'll ask @alexistoulotte